# Not able to run mrt command with meteor

Tags: meteorite

I got problem using the mrt command after I install meteorite. I got this error when using the mrt command '/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
'.

Hope you can help me.

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the response.. I got it managed.

This error is actually caused by the name of nodejs installed, meteorite looks for the node file where its actually named nodes on /usr/bin/env that is why he cant find the file.

I run this command: ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

it creates shortcut for nodejs as node.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) That means the mrt is not installed in `/usr/bin/env`. (One possibility is that it is somewhere inside a directory that is not in [PATH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)).)

2) On [Meteorite's git page](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite):

> As of Meteor 0.9.0, Meteorite is no longer required! You can now
>   install Atmosphere packages directly via the meteor tool.